# Problems creating folders in vb

Tags: vb.net

I can't create a folder in drive C: using VB.NET.  It says "Access is Denied".  I tried quite a lot of methods but it doesn't work.  I have tried to use this code:

```
If my.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\log.txt") Then
    Using writer As System.IO.TextWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\log.txt")
        writer.WriteLine(Me.Top & vbCrLf & "'top")
        writer.WriteLine(Me.Left & vbCrLf & "'lrft") ''sa scriu 
        writer.WriteLine(Me.Width & vbCrLf & "'width")
        writer.WriteLine(Me.Height & vbCrLf & "'height")
    End Using
Else 
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\log.txt")
    Using writer As System.IO.TextWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\log.txt")
        writer.WriteLine(100 & vbCrLf)
        writer.WriteLine(100 & vbCrLf) ''sa scriu 
        writer.WriteLine(100 & vbCrLf)
        writer.WriteLine(100 & vbCrLf)
    End Using
End If
```

What should I do?

Comment: write to `Users\....` the OS limits access to the root folder of the boot drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you are mixing the concept of *directories* (i.e. folders) with that of *files*.  First, you check to see if a folder called **log.txt** exists.  If it does exist, then you try to create a new file by the same name in the same location.  Conversely, if the **log.txt** folder doesn't exist, you create the folder, and then you try to create a file by the same name in the same location.  Either way, it's always going to fail.  You can't create a file called **log.txt** if there's already a folder by that same name in the same location.

I suspect that what you intended to do was to check if the folder C:\ existed before trying to create the file in that folder.  For instance, something like this:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.DirectoryExists("C:\") Then
    Using writer As System.IO.TextWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\log.txt")
    ' ...
    End Using
Else 
    Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\")
    Using writer As System.IO.TextWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText("C:\log.txt")
        ' ...
    End Using
End If
```

That certainly would make more logical sense, but, in this particular case, it's a bit silly since C:\ is the root folder for the drive, so it will always exist (unless the drive volume doesn't exist, in which case creating the folder will fail anyway).

As Plutonix pointed out in the comments above, even if that does work for you, it's still bad practice.  It's quite possible, if not likely, that the user will not have access to the root of the C: drive.  It would be far preferrable to write to *Isolated Storage*, or the system's temporary folder, or the user's application data folder, or anywhere else that is more likely to be accessible.

Comment: Drve C was an example , but i tried with "c:\Program Files\new folder\log.txt" ...... and with every location connected with drive C ,it wouldn't work.It keeps warning me "Acces is denied ."(and "New Folder "is a new folder which shoul've been created when running)

Comment: You can't use **c:\Program Files\new folder\log.txt** as the directory path.  You need to use **c:\Program Files\new folder** as the directory path.

Comment: @Electricspider you cant usually write to `Program Files` or `Program Files (x86)` or a sub directory thereof either. Use `C:\Temp` if you refuse to use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`